# LTspice: Is it possible to have different plot panes with different x-axes?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

Is it possible to have different x-axes for different plot panes in LTspice? For example, In following circuit, can I plot both output characteristics and transfer characteristic curves simultaneously in two plot panes? i.e. one x-axis is V1 and other x-axis is V2

[image]

Comment: right click "add plot plane" in the plot?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, of course it will add another plot. But I want two plots to be with different x-axes. For example, in this case, one is V1 and another is V2

Comment: I am not sure why a -1 is given though

Comment: @Pojj Unfortunately you'll have to get used to random strange votes, be they positive or negative. The feeling I get is that, sometimes, some people only skim over the text and vote at a based on the general impression, but I'm sure it's just my imagination.

Comment: I guess the question could be a bit clearer. In this case a small scribble (no one dislikes some heartwarming mouse paint action if it helps) might have helped showing what you want to achieve. Maybe saying "I want to plot Id vs. Vgs and Id vs Vds at the same time" or something would have made it a tad clearer.

Comment: Just getting used to the good practices here.. :) btw, I am impressed with how people willing share their knowledge.. will try do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep that is possible, but I'm not sure if your result will look like what you'll like:

1. In the plot view, right click and add a new plot plane.
2. Right click and uncheck "Sync. Horiz. Axes"
3. Now you can right click on each X-axis, at first it looks like it wouldn't work but after setting each axis, you will get two different ones.

The problem is, that it will not split the data nicely along the other axis.

What I mean is this:

[image: Multiple x-axes]

I'm not sure if that what you really want is possible which would probably be this:

[image: Mockup]

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this. Now I have top one, But I didn't get how the bottom one is generated.

Comment: With the magic of paint. I switched the sweeps, the data is always plotted with respect to sweep 1, so I switched sweep 1 to V2, got the plot and used paint to implement it in my picture. Like I said, I don't know of a way how to generate that in LTSpice directly.

Comment: Can you explain how did you choose the x-axis? For me, time is the default, but I want to plot v_out vs v_in.

Comment: @Shabnam you can right click on the x-axis to select a quantity. So you could enter V(in) instead of time. That would actually be a new question.